# Sabre: "UNABLE TO ISSUE PARTIAL CONNECTION-TKT ENTIRE CONNECTION" error in AirTicketRQ

Tags: sabre

I'm trying to do an international flight ticketing for Multicity, but trying to do book/ticket each segment individually, So which means am trying to call AirTicket for each Segment.

While doing it, I'm getting this error :-

> UNABLE TO ISSUE PARTIAL CONNECTION-TKT ENTIRE CONNECTION-2032

So in this case what am I supposed to do.

Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You will get better responses to questions if you can narrow it down to some specific lines and to explicitly ask a question about one particular thing. As explained in the guides, [don't just copy in your entire program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks will keep tat in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will help more if you post your requests, but it seems the segments (called 'married segments' if the below applies to your itinerary) you are trying to issue should be ticketed together, in a single, AirTicket call:

From the documentation at format-finder.sabre.com:

### --------------------------------

---

**Cause**:

This response occurs if you are trying to break Married Connection logic at the time of ticketing.

Note: At time of fare storage there are no longer married segment validation checks. Segment selection is permitted and fares may be stored even if segment selection breaks married segment logic.

Instead, the Sabre ticketing system performs Married Connection validation checks against the segments selected for ticket issuance at the point at which the ticket is issued. If the segments selected break a marriage, then the error response displays:

UNABLE TO ISSUE PARTIAL CONNECTION-TKT ENTIRE CONNECTION-1330

The only exception to this rule applies when issuing a ticket from a phase IV record. In this case, there is no married segment validation check performed.

**Solution:**

Issue the ticket for the complete itinerary or for all selected segments that qualify as married segments.

-or-

Phase IV the itinerary and issue the ticket(s).

Note: Your agency is responsible for the phase IV and for breaking married segment logic if a debit memo is issued by the carrier. See SabreTravelNetworkGuarantees for more information.

### --------------------------------

---

Normally, depending on the service you are using to 'shop' for flights, there is a 'MarriageGrp' indicator stating that the segments are 'married'.

Comment: Thank you very much, am getting very good picture of Sabre stuffs, you are a big help to me :) Sure will work on it :)

Comment: Sorry since am new to Stackoverflow forum, my reputation points are not enough to vote your answers :(

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help.